# Referencing .net framework 4.7.2 assembly from 4.6.1 project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to add dll which targets 4.7.2 .NET framework to a project which targets 4.6.1 .NET framework. Suprisingly it works fine, I always thought it's not allowed to reference higher version of .NET framework dll than the current project is built against. It was the case for .NET 4.0 and 4.5, can you do that now without any issues? I can't find any MSDN page that explains this.
However on my build server I get:

> The primary reference "***.dll" could not be resolved because it was
>   built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. This is a
>   higher version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1".

Why do I get this error on build server? (Windows Server 2012) and I don't get it on my local machine? One factor that can influence this is that 4.7.2 is not installed on the build server but it's installed on my machine. Why is it even allowed locally?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this is allowed locally either, with the error only showing up when you actually try to build. If using Visual Studio, there should be a warning along the lines of _The referenced project 'x' is targeting a higher framework version (4.7.2) than this project’s current target framework version (4.6.1). This may lead to build failures if types from assemblies outside this project’s target framework are used by any project in the dependency chain._

Comment: @Kei I also thought it's not allowed but apparently it is allowed. I checked in VS2017 and VS2019. Have you checked that?

Comment: I suspect that *at best* this is an undefined scenario; IMO it *probably shouldn't* work locally, but that could be an artifact of over-the-top vs side-by-side framework installs; chances of anyone fixing a glitch in .NET 4.6.1 build tooling at this point: zero

Comment: When Microsoft updates framework not all libraries get updated.  You only need the newer libraries if you are using the new libraries.  The update for 4.7.2 may not have any interactions with other classes and works.  The versions of the library are in the .proj file and I have edited the file when necessary.  When a new version of Net is installed the update utility often makes errors updating the .proj file.  It is easier to edit the proj (doesn't always work) than the alternative of creating a new project from scratch.

Comment: @MistyK, I tried it in VS2019 with an existing solution. It allowed me to add the reference, but threw an error on build.

Comment: I just tried again with a blank 4.6.1 console project and a 4.7.2  library project. This time, the build succeeded. Then, I tried again, this time instantiating a class that is defined in the library, and the build failed. My guess is that it succeeded the first time because the 4.6.1 project was referencing the 4.7.2 library, but not actually using anything from there. Thus, I think the reference to the 4.7.2 library was being ignored. But, as soon as I actually used something from the 4.7.2 project, the build stopped working. This is a different case though from what OP is describing.

Comment: @Kei I'll provide minimal reproducable code when I get a chance